# Entity Framework Single line CRUD

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Seeking advice for best practice

Very often I have to do the CRUD operation for a single record in my ASP.NET application.

For deletion, I was doing like

```
var myRecord = context.myTable.Find(myID);
if (myRecord != null)
{
    context.myTable.Remove(myRecord);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thinking about doing like

```
new context().myTable.Find(myID).Remove();
```

After reading some EF and repository pattern staff (especially [Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) ), I understand with the help of generic repository, at least I can do:

```
class UnitOfWork
{
    void RemoveRecord(myRecord)
    {
        var context = FindMyContext(myRecord); //[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/08/tip-24-how-to-get-the-objectcontext-from-an-entity.aspx)
        context.Entry(myRecord).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And I can use it like in my code:

```
new UnitOfWork.RemoveRecord(myRecord);
```

Is this a good idea?

Comment: One problem is that I may not want to do the context.SaveChanges here since there may be other things going on for this context, which should not be saved

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwwfTWMrM9k), it helped me a lot on the Unit Of Work topic. The thing about this is whether you really need to do the extra work or not and all of that depends on how big the project you are working on is.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly you may want to consider TransactionScope to control updates http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738523(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

First ask yourself what would be the added value of the repository and unit of work pattern on top of entity framework?

The context of Entity Framework already **is** a unit of work and already **is** a repository, so why create yet another one?

Also, you should create a context from the moment you need it and dispose it as soon as possible. Your service operation could look like:

```
 public void RemoveCustomer(int customerId)
 {
      using(var context = new MyDbContext())
      {
          var customer = context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == customerId); 
          if (customer==null) throw new BusinessException("Customer does not exist");
          context.Customers.Remove(customer);    
          context.SaveChanges();
      }
 }
```

Personally I inject this context with a IoC framework like using StructureMap.